# Antibody production in secondary immune response

Tags: human-biology, physiology, immunology, antibody

Can IgG antibodies be produced in the secondary immune response without the help of T cells?

Is the affinity of antibody for antigens higher during secondary immune response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  The secondary response [requires CD4<sup>+</sup> T cells](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/27/12192.full) to activate [memory B cells](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.iy.09.040191.001205).  That first paper actually gives some evidence that some of the rapidity could arise because T cells and memory B cells are in very close proximity to each other in germinal centers.

2) Yes.  The affinity of antibodies increases during the *initial* infection, both through [isotype switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotype_switching) and [affinity maturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_maturation), producing far superior antibodies.  Upon reactivation, memory B cells can undergo further somatic hupermutation.